# Is it possible to detect if an app in AppStore is developed with React Native?

Tags: android, ios, react-native, mobile, app-store

For Android there are a few decompiling applications such as Show Java. We are able to understand which platform used for the development of that Android app. Is there any way to understand if an iOS app developed by React Native or not ? Or can we detect which platform used to develop that iOS app ?

Answer (score 0):

If the IPA file is straight from the Appstore , the code section in the binary is encrypted with FairPlay (Apple's proprietary DRM). With Android you could use dex2jar, but unfortunately its not possible with iOS

Comment: Is it possible if I have the ipa?